# Inject code in between two scriptParsed events with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've got a library, included via `<script>`, that adds itself to the `window` object and then immediately gets referenced in the next `<script>`, i.e.:

```
<script src="lib.js"></script>
<script>
    var foo = new LIB.SomeClass();
    LIB.doStuff();
    ....
</script>
```

For profiling purposes, I now need to attach proxies to multiple properties of this library/the global `LIB` object *before* the next script fires (so before `LIB.SomeClass()` in the above).
All of this has to happen programmatically - I can't rely on hardcoded line numbers and I can't modify `lib.js` to fire a dummy event as soon as everything has been initialized.

My current approach is:

1. Wait for the `Debugger.scriptParsed` event for `lib.js`
2. Look up how many lines the `lib.js` file has (`event.endLine`)
3. Place a breakpoint right at the last line of `lib.js`(`Debugger.setBreakpointByUrl({lineNumber: ...})`
4. Reload the page, waiting for `Debugger.paused` to fire
5. Install the proxies in the `Debugger.paused` handler

But that seems unnecessarily convoluted, especially the reload feels like a bad hack.

**Question:**
Is there a way to inject my instrumentation code right after `Debugger.scriptParsed` but still guaranteed before loading the next script?
I've tried calling `Debugger.pause` in the `scriptParsed` handler, but that's too unreliable and just resulted in frequent race conditions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you to inject your .js file into the page.

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(
  //just put the location of your .js file
  fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/scripts/preload.js`, 'utf8'),
);
```